# Employment data from Fortune 500 companies

Tags: anova, t-test, p-value

I'm looking to compare the top 50 companies to the bottom 50 companies on the hiring of men and women. I would like to find out if there is a significant difference between the top 50 and the bottom 50? Such as: does the top 50 hire more males than the bottom 50? If not, it would prove the null hypothesis in that there is no significant difference. What would be the best way to design and how can I go about conducting the analysis?

Also, what would be the appropriate name of the study? (As in comparative, cross-sectional,etc.)

Comment: Welcome to our site! At the moment I think your question is really too broad to answer. Have a look at our guide to [how to write a good question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - you should probably be able to focus your question rather more specifically if you prioritise what aspects you need to ask about.

Comment: Note also that requests for data are off topic here. They can be asked on the [opendata.SE] SE site.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have researched extensively online on what to call the study I am attempting to construct. My study will be a descriptive study. So here is my 1st attempt in asking a clearer question. I'm taking EEO Data of employees working for the top 50 fortune 500 companies and the bottom 50 companies in that same list. I am attempting to identify which group (the top 50 or bottom 50) has a higher percentage of women or men working for them. (Or if there is no difference whatsoever.) I am attempting to identify the variables in this study. Hopefully, this is clearer...